# Encrypting payload using JWE (Alg: ECDH_ES, Enc: A256GCM) .NET5

Tags: c#, encryption, .net-5, jwe

Is there a way to encrypt data using `Alg: ECDH_ES, Enc: A256GCM` in .NET 5 - OS: Linux?

**Data to encrypt:**

```
"{\"num\":\"1234567891234567\",\"ram\":\"1223\"}"
```

**What I tried:**

I used .NET jose-jwt library to encrypt a payload using `Alg: ECDH_ES, Enc: A256GCM` and it works pretty good in Windows. The problem is that it doesn't work in Linux because `JWT.Encode()` expects a `CngKey` which is only available in Windows platforms. (Check the git issue [here](https://github.com/dvsekhvalnov/jose-jwt/issues/176) with all the code)

```
string token = Jose.JWT.Encode(json, pubCngKey, JweAlgorithm.ECDH_ES, JweEncryption.A256GCM);
```

On the other hand, I have come across multiple posts from Scott Brady talking about JWE explaining how to use JWE in .NET Core but I wasn't able to achieve what I needed either.

- https://www.scottbrady91.com/c-sharp/json-web-encryption-jwe-in-dotnet-core
- https://www.scottbrady91.com/c-sharp/pem-loading-in-dotnet-core-and-dotnet
- https://www.scottbrady91.com/openssl/creating-elliptical-curve-keys-using-openssl
- https://www.scottbrady91.com/c-sharp/ecdsa-key-loading

He has an example of encrypting a JWT Token using `System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt` but I didn't find a way to use that to achieve encryption using `Alg: ECDH_ES, Enc: A256GCM` and for any kind of data. In his examples, he is encrypting an Authentication Token and I just want to encrypt a JSON payload like:

```
"{\"num\":\"1234567891234567\",\"ram\":\"1223\"}"
```

Even if I wanted to use his method, He achieves encryption with the following code but I haven't been able to load my **EC public key** as `X509Certificate2`.

```
var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
{
    Audience = "you",
    Issuer = "me",
    Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new List<Claim> {new Claim("sub", "scott")}),
    EncryptingCredentials = new X509EncryptingCredentials(new X509Certificate2("key_public.cer"))
};

string token = handler.CreateEncodedJwt(tokenDescriptor);
```

To use `Alg: ECDH_ES, Enc: A256GCM` with his method I wrote the code below but I couldn't test it because I wasn't able to load my **EC public key** as `X509Certificate2`.

```
EncryptingCredentials = new X509EncryptingCredentials(new X509Certificate2("key_public.cer"), SecurityAlgorithms.EcdsaSha256Signature, SecurityAlgorithms.EcdsaSha256)
```

When I tried to load **my EC public key** I get the following exception

> Internal.Cryptography.CryptoThrowHelper+WindowsCryptographicException: Cannot find the requested object.

This is my **EC Public key** generated from a private key with curve `prime256v1`

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MFkwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcDQgAE6z98vdUZNeuaEXcoxLY9dSylEI7H
Nr+Uj/CYwlbE97l4PB5pZw0R3fKshknUKb2t5I+2v+XD4P9fsqJqBJZhkQ==
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```